# Entity Framework 6 Code First Table Per Type (TBT) With Abstract Generic Base Class - Invalid Column Errors

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6, code-first, table-per-type

I have the following database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batches] (
    [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BatchTypeId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Batches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Batches_BatchTypes] FOREIGN KEY ([BatchTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BatchTypes] ([BatchTypeId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PayrollDiscrepancyBatches]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT PK_PayrollDiscrepancyBatches_Batches PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PayrollDiscrepancyBatches_Batches FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Batches (Id)
)
```

I'm in the process of trying to make the `Batch` entity object generic. Here's what I have for the `Batch` class:

```
public abstract class Batch<TBatchRequest, TBatchSummary>
        where TBatchRequest : BatchRequest 
        where TBatchSummary : BatchSummary {

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public BatchTypeEnum BatchTypeId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100), Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TBatchSummary> Summaries { get; set; } = new List<TBatchSummary>();

        public virtual ICollection<TBatchRequest> Requests { get; set; } = new List<TBatchRequest>();

        public virtual ICollection<BatchExport> Exports { get; set; } = new List<BatchExport>();
}
```

And here's the derived class:

```
[Table("PayrollDiscrepancyBatches")]
public class PayrollDiscrepancyBatch : Batch<PayrollDiscrepancyBatchRequest, PayrollDiscrepancyBatchSummary> {
    public PayrollDiscrepancyBatch() {
        BatchTypeId = BatchTypeEnum.PayrollDiscrepancy;
    }
}
```

In my DBContext, I Have the following DBSet:

```
public virtual DbSet<PayrollDiscrepancyBatch> PayrollDiscrepancyBatches { get; set; }
```

I can't set the DbSet type to Batch, because Batch requires knowledge of the generic constraints.

Now, when I attempt to retrieve data from the database for these types, the following error is thrown:

```
Message: Invalid column name 'PayrollDiscrepancyBatch_Id'.
Invalid column name 'BatchTypeId'. Invalid column name 'CreatedDate'.
Invalid column name 'CreatedBy'. Invalid column name
'PayrollDiscrepancyBatch_Id'.
```

From the number of invalid columns shown in the error message, it would appear that EF is treating this relationship as a `Table Per Concrete Type`. With that in mind, I added the following to the overridden `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PayrollDiscrepancyBatch>()
            .Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties().ToTable("Batches"))
            .HasKey(m => m.Id);
```

This still causes an error, but reduced the number of "invalid columns" to just one:

```
Invalid column name 'PayrollDiscrepancyBatch_Id'
```

At this point, I'm at a loss. Is the fact that my base class is generic causing me issues? If so, does anyone know a way to get around this? Perhaps I need another table, `BatchBases` that will be an abstract `non generic` class which `Batches` inherits from?

Any insight will be greatly appreciated!